# Creating a dynamic GridPane (add and remove rows)

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

So I need to add and delete Rows in a GridPane when selecting or deselecting a `MenuItem`.

So when selecting a `MenuItem` it should add 1 or 2 rows in the existing GridPane. When deselecting it should remove 1 or 2 of the rows.

There is always a fixed row that cannot be removed. the added or deleted rows should be added or removed above this fixed row.

For example:

Add row:

```
added ---------  

added ---------  

fixed ---------
```

Remove row:

```
removed 

removed 

fixed -----------
```

I know how to handle the actions for the MenuItems. I only need help with the dynamic Grid Pane.

There is a built in function addRow for GridPanes, maybe its the one to use. How can I solve this? Thanks! All tips appreciated.

Comment: Would it be easier to just hide/show rows rather than adding and removing them? Does this fits your needs?

Comment: Yes I suppose that will work, but it can't be a space between top and bottom row. In that case they should be put together.

Comment: There is a Java swing example how it works, except for adding the row under instead of above:  http://www.lionblogger.com/adding-and-removing-components-dynamically-from-jpanel/.  Is it a good way to use this example and integrate in my project?  How can I use Swing components when using JavaFX?

Comment: I created an answer for you. If it is not totally necessary you should not mix Swing and JavaFX (and in this case it can be achieved with pure JavaFX code).

Answer (score 1):

This answer is about to hide and show rows of a `GridPane` rather than adding and removing them, as I think it is more reasonable to not create new objects every time when the `MenuItem` is selected.

I have made you an example that contains a `GridPane` and a `Button` (rather than a `MenuItem` but it has the same function here). On the press of the button the first two row of the `GridPane` is shown or hidden.

I have used the [RowConstraints](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/RowConstraints.html) class: I have added three `RowConstraints` for the `GridPane` and then on button press the [maxHeightProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/RowConstraints.html#maxHeightProperty) of the first two constraints is set to 0 (hide) or 30 (show).

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private SimpleBooleanProperty expanded = new SimpleBooleanProperty(true);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);


            VBox vbox = new VBox();


            GridPane grid = new GridPane();
            // Just to see that the lines are actually added
            grid.setGridLinesVisible(true);
            grid.setPrefWidth(200);

            grid.getRowConstraints().add(new RowConstraints(30));
            grid.getRowConstraints().add(new RowConstraints(30));

            grid.addRow(2, new Label("I am fixed!"));
            grid.getRowConstraints().add(new RowConstraints(30));



            Button showOrHideButton = new Button();
            showOrHideButton.setOnAction((e) -> {
                expanded.set(expanded.not().get());
            });


            vbox.getChildren().addAll(showOrHideButton, grid);

            expanded.addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
                if(newVal) {
                    grid.getRowConstraints().get(0).setMaxHeight(30);
                    grid.getRowConstraints().get(1).setMaxHeight(30);
                    showOrHideButton.setText("Hide");
                } else {
                    grid.getRowConstraints().get(0).setMaxHeight(0);
                    grid.getRowConstraints().get(1).setMaxHeight(0);
                    showOrHideButton.setText("Show");
                }
            });

            expanded.set(false);


            root.setCenter(vbox);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

It produces something like this:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks!   So I hade some problems to get it to work, so I changed it into 2 separate buttons, 1 show and 1 hide. And put an event action on the buttons. It does the right thing on the show button. On hide it removes the 2 rows but keeps 1 row above. Then it's stuck in exception

Comment: Please update the question, rather than post an answer with the update. And when you update the question, please post the whole code you have.

Comment: Got it to work. Tried to add X columns to every row:  grid.add(new Label("  "),count,i); where count is a for loop, i is row index. Will not generate a correct result. Is there a way to add X columns to a RowConstraints()?

Comment: Generally, RowConstrainnts (as in its name) describes some containts on a row. A sibling exists which class is called ColumnConstraint, that can be used similarly to columns. I don't see your code, I don't know how did you adapt the answer. But:
this question is about how to show/hide the first two columns of a Grid. This question is answered. If you have further problems/questions ask a separate question.

Comment: Yes true, I will test more with ColumnConstraint. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks!   So I had some problems to get it to work, so I changed it into 2 separate buttons, 1 show and 1 hide. And put an event action on the buttons. It does the right thing on the show button. On hide it removes the 2 rows but keeps 1 row above, not sure why. Then it's stuck in exception.

```
@FXML
private void add_act(ActionEvent event) {
    SimpleBooleanProperty expanded = new SimpleBooleanProperty(true);

        // Just to see that the lines are actually added
        grid.setGridLinesVisible(true);

        grid.getRowConstraints().add(new RowConstraints(30)); //add 1 row
        grid.getRowConstraints().add(new RowConstraints(30)); //add 1 row

        grid.addRow(2, new Label("I am fixed!")); //on index 2 write label

        show.setOnAction((e) -> {
            expanded.set(expanded.not().get());
        });

}

@FXML
private void hide_act(ActionEvent event) {
    SimpleBooleanProperty expanded = new SimpleBooleanProperty(true);

        // Just to see that the lines are actually added
        grid.getRowConstraints().get(0).setMaxHeight(0);
        grid.getRowConstraints().get(1).setMaxHeight(0);

        show.setOnAction((e) -> {
            expanded.set(expanded.not().get());
        });
}
```

And also I need to keep track on which row index is added or removed. Probably done with: setRowIndex(button, 1), setColumnIndex(button, 2), setConstraints(label, 3, 1); // column=3 row=1